# Use scrapy response.css for style tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'd like to extract next pages from an initial website with the function `response.css()` from the scrapy library. I don't find any hints on how to use that function when the link for further pages are embedded like this:

`<li style="text-align: left;"><a href="/the/desired/link">NameOfPage</a></li>`

Is this possible with scrapy or should I use anything else like BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Can you share the website link?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden it's a website of our intranet at work, so sadly no :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if it can be achieved using `css`, but with `xpath` it is quite easy to express:

```py
response.xpath('//li[contains(@style, "text-align: left;")]')
```

xpath expressions are really powerful, you might give them a try before pulling in another library.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who still search for this answer. You can try this:

`response.css("li [style='text-align: left;'] a::attr(href)").get()`